# Android: performance Google Maps iframe on website browsing

Tags: android, google-maps

web browser on android device don't show google-map iframe, and instead of it ask to sing in.

Is it possible on android google maps works on the site the same to others platforms 
(without asking about google maps aplication on device)

thank You

Comment: You need to provide more details and/or a link to live code.  Otherwise, this question is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

have found answer for my question:

iOS does not have a browsable file system like a computer, so even if Safari supported file uploads, you would not be able to browse to the file to select it.

This is for security reasons as every iOS app runs in a sandbox and has no access to other apps data.

You can download or write App so as to upload the Photos and Videos..